# How do I turn off AVG Anti-Virus Network Edition 8.5?

Tags: avg-antivirus

I'm trying to install Windows 7 and it says that I need to turn off my anti-virus.  I'm running AVG Anti-Virus Network Edition 8.5 and I can't figure out how to turn it off.  How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

start > run > type **services.msc** and click OK

stop all AVG related services.

or ...

uninstall AVG temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the system tray AVG icon and click Exit.

Comment: this will only stop the AVG control center.

Answer (score 0):

Open the AVG 8.5 Control Center, by right clicking on the AVG icon on task bar.

Click on Open AVG Interface.

Double click on Resident Shield

Deselect the option to "Enable Resident Shield."

Save changes, and exit the application.

To re-enable AVG 8.5, please select "Enable Resident Shield" again.